# Why do self sign ssl certificates throw secutity warnings?

Tags: ssl

Why does self signed SSL certs throw an unsafe warning? They actually have a smaller attack profile, and not as easily cracked like commercial ssl from a CA. So in reality, a third party cert is more unsafe than a self signed one. Even the wiki page says this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

Answer (score 4):

A self-signed certificate does not create a security warning **if it is configured as trusted in the browser**. If it is not known as trusted yet the browser has no way to find out who issued the certificate: it can be the original certificate from the target server or it can be a certificate created by man-in-the-middle attacker. And that's why it is throwing a security warning.

With a CA signed certificate instead the browser can forward the trust it has in the CA (i.e. it is in the local trust store) to the certificates issued by this CA. This means does not need any more to trust every new certificate explicitly up-front but it is enough to trust the specific CA which signed the certificate. This makes the process of rolling out certificates much simpler.

Of course, the risk of the CA model is that one might put too much trust into a CA. The problem of the self-signed model is that you have to find a way to distribute the certificate before connecting to a site in a secure way to the browser - which means that you somehow need to trust this secure distribution of the certificate and that you will run into the same or even worse problems with this than you have in the CA model.

Comment: So in other words, the browser mechanism is wrong. The final security level in the end is the same, its just the new certificate "notice" is mislabeled as a "warning".  The lame consumer can't tell if its ok or not to continue to the site due to the way they mis-word this notice. Trusting outside sources via "is this key in a CA database I have access to"  seems like a money scam on some level mainly because of the way the certificate sites use the warning as a marketing angle.

Comment: It would also seem that the self signed would be more secure as there is not a copy of the server key in someone else's database that might get hacked....

Comment: @drtechno:  The browser cannot distinguish a "true" self-signed certificate from an attacker issued self-signed certificate because there are no information available on how to distinguish these - both are self-signed certificates anybody could create. Which means it could be an attacker and that's why the browser is warning the user. And, calling it a money scam would imply that you have to pay for certificates. But since many years (even before Let's Encrypt) there are free certificates available.

Comment: @drtechno: *"there is not a copy of the server key in someone else's database that might get hacked."*  - there is no copy of the servers private key in some database. You don't provide this private key to the CA when getting a certificate issued but keep it yourself.

Comment: @drtechno: Also, you can use self-signed certificates in the browser without any warnings. You just have to add them up-front as trusted, similar to how the CA are added up-front. Because then the browser can actually verify that the certificate sent by the server is the expected one.

Comment: "Adding them up front" meaning you give the client a cert to install on the browser? I can see that being a angle to use if I did't want ssl cert but the intended people. I imagine there could be a way to not give new certs and "must provide pre-shared key" method. I'm still wondering how a hacker could issue a ssl key instead of the server unless they already hacked the client, and in that case it wouldn't matter if its SSL or not , signed by CA or self signed. Because the hacker already has access in the client and not on the outside snooping on ip packets.

Comment: @drtechno: Which part you don't understand: how the attacker could get man in the middle in the local network (many ways to do this: arp spoofing, dns spoofing, fake hotspots...) or how the attacker could create a self-signed certificate in the name of the target server (same as the server owner would do)? There is no need to have access to the client for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165167/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-drtechno).

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed carts throw an unsafe warning because your computer does not trust your CA, but (instructions different depending on the environment) you can set your computer to trust your CA.